# how can I set the metadata of an image using WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, image-processing

WPF has an ImageSource which has a BitmapMetadata.

However, the Metadata property is read only an the BitmapMetadata is frozen.

So I can I modify the metadata of an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

var frame = ...;

BitmapMetadata newMetadata = ...;

**var newFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(frame, frame.Thumbnail, newMetadata, frame.ColorContexts);**

var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

encoder.Frames.Add(newFrame);

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the WPF imaging API doesn't allow you to modify the image metadata... However, you can still do it with GDI+ (System.Drawing)